# how to access a shared folder on a windows machine with iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone, file, networking, sharing

I was wondering if anyone could help point me in the right direction if I am trying to write the contents of a file from a shared folder on a windows machine to an array on the iphone over a wifi connection.

could I do it with initWithContentsOfURL??

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

`initWithContentsOfUrl` reads files produced by the `writeToURL:atomically:` method.  These two methods require an HTTP server to work, so you would need to setup IIS or Apache on the windows box.

What you want is an iPhone [samba client](http://ahttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)).

> Samba is an open source implementation
>   of networking protocols to share files
>   and printers between Unix computers
>   and Windows.

I did some [searches](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&q=iPhone+samba+client+library&aq=f&oq=&aqi=) but didn't find anything worth linking.  *Someone else chime in here...*

Comment: thanks for the info, it seems like there are some apps that do this so I think that it must be possible, but just can't seem find any information about it

Answer (score 0):

I just started on building a simple windows network share library for the iOS:
https://github.com/38leinaD/tango

At the moment it only allows to list a directory, but i plan to extend it to at least reading an writing files. But i don't know when i will find the motivation. SMB/CIFS is a very dirty protocol and not much fun to work with...